# AudioClip.Length is incorrect when loading from UnityWebRequestMultimedia GetAudioClip

Tags: unity-game-engine, audioclip

When I get an unity audio clip from firebase by url

```
    var request = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(url, AudioType.MPEG);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    var clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(request);
    print("success..." + clip.length);
```

audio clip real length is 4.86, but after download clip.length is 8.1

Answer (score 0):

my upload audioclip used unity micphone record , and use "SavWav" Convert to mp3 data,
download audioclip length is a unity bug bug not fixed ,

i use `SavWav.TrimSilence(clip, 0, (clip_)=>{...}` get the correct length

Hope that helps

Comment: can get SavWav from https://github.com/Team-on/Unity3D-save-audioClip-to-MP3